# Room. Составить Entity и Dao по JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Нужна помощь в составлении Entity для Room и Dao для insert.

```
{
    "response": [{
            "title": "iPhone X",
            "value": "120000",
            "other": [{
                "color": "red",
                "type": "phone"
            }]
        },
        {
            "title": "iPhone 6",
            "value": "120000",
            "other": [{
                    "color": "red",
                    "type": "phone"
                },
                {
                    "color": "green",
                    "type": "phone"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
open class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun get_string(str: List<Specialty>): String? {
        if (str == null) return null
        val others = StringBuilder()
        for (s in str) others.append(s).append(",")
        return others.toString()
    }
}

data class UsersBase(@SerializedName("response") var response: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf())

@Parcelize
@Entity
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long = 0,

    @SerializedName("title") var title: String = "",
    @SerializedName("value") var value: String = ""

    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
    @SerializedName("other") var other: Array<Other>
) : Parcelable {}

@Parcelize
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Item::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("itemId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
data class Other(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long = 0,

    @SerializedName("color") var color: String = "",
    @SerializedName("type") var type: String = "",
    var itemId: Long = 0
) : Parcelable


@Database(entities = [Item::class, Other::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}

//Dao.kt
//Так записываю без List<Other>
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(item: List<Item>): LongArray?
```

Comment: А какого рода помощь вам нужна? Тут же всё просто - составьте по классу для каждого типа объекта в JSON кроме `response`. Т.е. два класса. И сделайте, видимо, связь один-ко-многим между ними, добавив констраинты всякие, id и прочее. Что именно и как добавлять - не ясно, слишком мало информации. По идее с бэка должны хотя бы ID для объектов в `response` приходить. Коли их не добавить - используйте, например `title` как первичный ключ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб непонятно как правильно составить, чтобы во вторую таблицу могли записываться данные и сохранялась связь. Если в модели используется var other:List<Other> = listOf(), то требует Room TypeConvertor, не получается его использовать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил описание

Comment: Самый верный способ - не выяснять как и можно ли вообще настроить автоматическую запись вложенных сущностей в БД. Уберите вложенный список из родительского класса и записывайте вложенные сущности вручную, отдельно. Также их и собирайте обратно, если нужно, наполняя данными отдельный класс из классов, полученных из БД.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как я могу достучаться до Other? Только до Item получается.

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы имеете под `достучаться до Other`

Comment: Возможно, я понял что вы имеете в виду и как вашу проблему решить. Сделайте 3 разных модели для каждой сущности. Одна будет представлять собой то, что пришло от сервера в JSON. Вторая будет преставлением таблицы в БД. Третья будет представлением данных, вытащенных из БД. Так вы сможете править любую модель на любом слое логики, не затрагивая другие слои.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сейчас я держу в БД Item. А теперь хочу созать таблицу с Other, где перечислю все цвета и название типа, но я не могу из ответа достучаться до сущности. data.response - это MutableList<Item>.

Comment: Создайте классы `NwItem` и `NwOther` (Nw - network). Именно их укажите в качестве типа данных для ответа от сервера. Когда будете в БД данные писать - создавайте экземпляры `Item` и `Other` из данных полученных с сервера.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как можно обойтись без класса "корня" json при парсинге? В данном случае это класс UsersBase.

Comment: Обойтись можно, если повесить interceptor на все сетевые запросы и вручную доставать из ответа нужные данные. Нужно оно вам или нет - решать вам

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за ответ, интерсепторы еще не применял на практике.